# How can I upload pictures with queue in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

When uploading many images, and the size is large, it takes a lot of time, and sometimes the site appears to be unavailable due to the large size. Can this problem be solved?

Comment: Yes. Read about https://laravel.su/docs/8.x/queues

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using ["spatie/laravel-medialibrary"](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary). Library came with build in "queue" solution for resize and optimize.